# Building a char array with hex bytes from string values

Tags: c++, hex, chararray

I'm trying to build a char array that contains hex bytes on the fly.

I effectively want to create:

```
unsigned char myHexArray[] = { 0xfc, 0x48, 0x83, 0xe4, 0xf0, 0xe8...);
```

But I want to create it from a string like so:

```
std::string str = "fc4883e4f0e8...";
```

I usually write code in C#, although now I realise that's not really writing code!

I'd really appreciate some help here.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: What are "hex bytes"? That's just a different way to write an integer or a char in your case. Can you please clarify input and expected output? The second example looks like you actually want to parse hex numbers from a string and turn them into characters or numbers. But it's not really clear, at least to me.

Comment: yeah, sorry, I think part of my problem is terminology.

So I want to take the first two chars from str "fc", and pass them in to the first index of myHexArray = so myHexArray[0] = 0xfc;

Comment: @Mike Try this: https://godbolt.org/z/hdvGx6PMY

Comment: All writing of code is *really* writing code. The language is 100% irrelevant.

Comment: @molbdnilo - thanks for clearing that up. It was a flippant joke...